# PostgreSQL FTS: search text[] column

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple question: is it possible to search through a column with the text[] type when making a `@@` query in PostgreSQL?

E.g., something akin to

`to_tsvector(text[]) @@ plainto_tsquery('search this text')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But as a workaround, you can create a text column which is the joined string of the text[] elements and gets updated whenever the text[] column does.